# Mongodb error code 10068 or 17287 with rails 4.1 and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to use mongoid with Rails 4.1.0 app and am getting error 17287 on moongodb 2.6.0 (same as 10068 on earlier versions of mongodb).
Here is the error message:

```
The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Query @length=127 @request_id=5 @response_to=0 @op_code=2004 @flags=[] @full_collection_name="educandose_development.users" @skip=0 @limit=-1 @selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>{"$oid"=>BSON::ObjectId('534d6f4f6372618443000000')}}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} @fields=nil> failed with error 17287: "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $oid" See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/errors.md for details about this error.
```

Any idea of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After looking for a while, I realized that the new json cookies serializer on rails 4.1 breaks moped queries on devise resources.

To fix that, remove the following line on the cookies_serializer.rb initializer

```
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :json
```

You may want to get the old sessions_store.rb file back with content similar to:

```
YourApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_yourapp_session'
```

or try the master branch of devise.

Take a look here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2949#issuecomment-40520236
and here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/2882

Comment: This then leads to:  ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
 format version 4.8 required; 123.34 given) if you have not cleared cookies.  Clear your cookies and this goes away.

Answer (score 10):

Temporarily, until moped/session/json formatting is fixed, I'm using:

```
# app/models/concerns/zero_oid_fix.rb
module ZeroOidFix
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def serialize_from_session(key, salt)
      record = to_adapter.get((key[0]["$oid"] rescue nil))
      record if record && record.authenticatable_salt == salt
    end
  end
end
```

And in devise model:

```
class User

  devise :database_authenticatable, ...

  # NOTE: Has to be after devise
  include ZeroOidFix

  ...
end
```

Hope this answer will get obsolete fast.

Comment: This fix worked for me, thank you. However, I don't quite understand why this error is happening and how this fix work. Could you please explain what is happening?

Comment: @Kira BSON ObjectId serialisation changed from storing it as plain hex string to object `{ "$oid": "hexstring" }` so it's more aligned with MongoDB's Extended JSON formatting convention (changed in one library but not the other).

Comment: This fix works like a charm for mongoid 4.0.0 and rails 4.1.4.

Comment: This breaks if you check the `remember me` check box. The next time you open the browser it throws error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Comment out the line below from the **cookies_serializer.rb**

   Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :json
2. Delete cookies.
3. Restart server.

Worked for me on "rails 4.1.4, devise 3.2.4, mongoid 4.0.0"